# In Android Studio Arctic Fox Canary 8, the app level build.gradle does not generate `allprojects` section and causes error when manually added

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When creating a new project in Android Studio Arctic Fox Canary 8, this is the app level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha08"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When creating the same new project in the Android Studio 4.1.2, the app-level build.gradle file is this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

One of the libraries I am using requires the `allprojects`

I manually tried to add the `allprojects` section in Canary 8, received this error:

```
 problem occurred evaluating root project 'My Application'.
> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'
```

Why was the `allprojects` in Android Studio Canary 8 was removed and how can I add it back so that I can use the libraries?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

In `settings.gradle` you can add the repositories you want to add to the project

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
   repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
   repositories {
      google()
      mavenCentral()
      jcenter()
      maven { url "https://maven.xyz.com" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 51):

In `settings.gradle` just comment out the whole block

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When I comment out this block, I get: 
Failed to resolve: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0
Failed to resolve: androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.0.0-beta01
Failed to resolve: androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0
Failed to resolve: androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.0-beta01
Failed to resolve: androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2
(+5 more)
Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts and migrate your build to other Maven repositories.

Answer (score 43):

Go to `setting.gradle` and replace the line:

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
```

with:

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
```

That's a gradle setting which allows this to work.

Comment: After applying this setting, project sync successful. I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 1 (For ARM)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.5.2 on a M1 macbook pro.

Comment: can you please tell us what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 28):

> In new release of Android, provide a new way to define your repositories. Before this release we used **build.gradle(Project level)** file to define repositories. Now you should write then into **settings.gradle** file. That's why It collides with Gradle plugin and generate this error message:

```
Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'
```

**We can solve it in two possible ways.**

**Solution 1:**

> **Use previous way:** Not to use **dependencyResolutionManagement** for repositories in **settings.gradle** file

Just keep settings.gradle file like below:

```
/*dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}*/
rootProject.name = "YourAppName"
include ':app'
```

Keep build.gradle(Project level) like below;

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' // If you use
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Change or add the line at top of the build.gradle(Module level)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' // If you use
}
```

**Solution 2:**

> **Use new way:** Use **dependencyResolutionManagement** for repositories in **settings.gradle** file

Just keep settings.gradle file like below:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "YourAppName"
include ':app'
```

Keep build.gradle(Project level) like below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' // If you use
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Keep build.gradle(Module level) file as previous:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'// If you use
}
```

Hopefully you overcome your problem.

Comment: I just wanted to know is it a right way of doing it?
I wanted to add this dependency 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0' which requires maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } repositories.
Its wokring....I have directly added it in setting.gradle ->
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

Answer (score 9):

`allProjects{}` block is removed from the updated version of gradle. So, in settings.gradle you can add the repositories you want to download and add to the project

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon

        maven {
            url 'https://your/url/to/download/repository/'
            credentials {
                username = "your username"
                password = "your password"
            }
        }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 4):

just keep this line in settings.gradle

1. include ':app' (Put in First line)
2. comment rest of code if any.

Comment: life saver, tnx.

Answer (score 3):

Google has made some changes in the project label Gradle.

you can fix this by removing all project label configuration to setting.gradle file.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Remove this code in the Gradle file and all your plugins code in setting.gradle file. Like below.

```
    pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0-alpha03'
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0-alpha03'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.10'
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "MVVMDEMO"
include ':app'
```