# Failed to resolve: com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.7.0 #410

Tags: osmdroid, osmbonuspack

I am getting error while trying to implement a routing system into my map.

Here is the error : Failed to resolve: com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.7.0
Affected Modules: app

I have the following dependencies : implementation 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.7.0'. Tried the local one as well : ``` compile(name: 'osmbonuspack_v6.7.0', ext: 'aar') implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.10' implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0' implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7' implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1'

I have this in my repositories :

`repositories { google() jcenter() maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }`

How can I get this to work?

Comment: jcenter repository has been shut down. If the osmbonuspack was only available in jcenter then it is missing now. Try to download the mentioned source code of [GitHub project osmbonuspack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/releases/tag/6.7.0) in the desired version and build and install it yourself by executing `gradlew install`. Afterwards it will be available in the project you are trying to build.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggesetion! it was avaiable through maven but I couldn't get that to work for some reason. I don't have too much experience how would I build and install it myself?

Comment: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/HowToInclude Heres the guide I was following. I couldn't get either one to work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: The shown way via Jitpack looks quite good and should work.

Comment: I was able to get it to work via Jitpack, thanks so much!

Comment: I couldn't get the local install to work either. Building from source didn't sound easy but people on SO are complaining about the help by MKergall. After 20minutes on SO I drew the conclusions below.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly these troubles and attempted to solve them using the newly refreshed and updated help wiki on https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/HowToInclude

What it doesn't tell you, possibly related to the newness of Android Studio Arctic Fox is https://stackoverflow.com/a/68012797

ie it is `settings.gradle` into which we must add our link to jitpack. This is contrary to advice to use project (root) level `build.gradle`, even the advice to add it under `allprojects` instead of `buildscripts`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

That caused: `Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'build.gradle'`

What eventually worked was:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

in `settings.gradle`. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68012797 for that. Most of it was already coded, I simply added `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }`

Comment: but my case its working using this   repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
in setting.gradle file other than both same